# Reload pod when secret changes

Tags: kubernetes

Let's say that I have a running pod named `my-pod`

`my-pod` reads the secrets from `foobar-secrets`

Now let's say that I update some value in `foobar-secrets`

```
kubectl patch secret foobar-secrets --namespace kube-system --context=cluster-1 --patch "{\"data\": {\"FOOBAR\": \"$FOOBAR_BASE64\"}}"
```

What I should do to restart/reload the pod in order to get the new value?

Comment: A modern approach to this problem is by practicing _disposable servers_ aka _immutable infrastructure_. A good way to do it is to use `kustomize` and `SecretGenerator`, it will automatically deploy new pods for a `Deployment` when a `Secret` is changed. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kustomize/

Comment: I am not sure if I can use kustomize right now

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/stakater/Reloader is the usual solution for a fully standalone setup. Another option is https://github.com/jimmidyson/configmap-reload or similar but that requires coordination with the daemon process to have an API of some kind for reloading.